# How to cut the lower values when caclulating percentile?

Tags: python, numpy

If I calculate 90 percentile using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
p = np.percentile(a, 90)
print (p)
```

It cuts the highest value so the result is:

```
9.1
```

How to cut instead the lower values so the output would be:

```
2
```

Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be fundamentally a math question, not a programming question. The bottom 90th percentile is simply the top 10th percentile. No particular programming knowledge is required to solve the problem, just a proper understanding of the problem.

Comment: Agree. Can't close it myself though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the 10th percentile, not the 90th.

```
p = np.percentile(a, 10)
print (p)
# 1.9
```